# How to retrieve a task from a future in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

Let say I have the following code to run multiple task in parallel.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=connections) as executor:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [
        loop.run_in_executor(
             executor,
             fun,
             arg
        )
        for i in range(connections)
    ]
    for result in await asyncio.gather(*futures):
        # I want to access the futures task here
        pass
```

Is it possible to read the the futures' task once it has been executed?

Comment: What is the future's task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to read the the futures' task once it has been executed?

In asyncio, the word *task* has a specialized meaning, referring to a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) that subclasses [`Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future) specialized for driving coroutines.

In your code, `asyncio.gather()` returns results, and you also have the `futures` variable that contains the `Future` objects which can also be used to access the same results. If you need to access additional information (like the original `fun` or `arg`), you can attach it to the appropriate `Future` or use a dict to map it. For example:

```
futures = []
for conn in connections:
    fut = loop.run_in_executor(executor, fun, arg)
    fut.conn = conn  # or other info you need
await asyncio.wait(futures)
# at this point all the futures are done, and you can use future.result()
# to access the result of an individual future, and future.conn to obtain
# the connection the future was created for
```

Comment: Thank you! That was really simple, I just need to attach the original function or argument to the `Future` object.